# Merging two files containing sorted numbers into one

Tags: c#, file, mergesort

The task is to merge 2 text files containing sorted integers into one file. Each number in both files is stored in new line(there are no empty lines,and only numbers are stored). Requirements are that if `file1` has n numbers and `file2` has m numbers, running time must be O(n+m) and memory consumption O(1).

My current solution is based on this algorithm:

> ```
> while (not end of List A and not end of List B)
>     if (List A current item <= List B current item)
>         output List A current item
>         advance List A index
>     else
>         output List B current item
>         advance List B index
>
> // At this point, one of the lists is empty.
> // Output remaining items from the other
> while (not end of List A)
>     output List A current item
>     advance List A index
>
> while (not end of List B)
>     output List B current item
>     advance List B index
> ```

The solution is working fine, I've tested it for different cases.But, I'm looking for you opinion and suggestions, how can I improve the code, since it is quite huge.

Also, can I avoid assigning value to `item 1` and `item 2` variables at beginning?  If I leave them unassigned, even if I pass them `value` visual studio is returning error saying that I'm using unassigned variables in `while loop`.

```
public static void Merge(string pathInputFile1, string pathInputFile2, string pathOutputFile)
    {
        int item1 = 0;
        int item2 = 0;
        bool endOfFile1 = false;
        bool endOfFile2 = false;
        string temp;

        var inputFile1 = File.OpenText(pathInputFile1);
        var inputFile2 = File.OpenText(pathInputFile2);
        temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
        if (temp == null)
        {
            endOfFile1 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
        }
        temp = inputFile2.ReadLine();
        if (temp == null)
        {
            endOfFile2 = true;
        }
        else
        {
            item2 = Int32.Parse(temp);
        }

        while (!endOfFile1 && !endOfFile2)
        {
            if (item1 < item2)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item1);
                }
                temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    endOfFile1 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }

            }
            else if (item1 == item2)
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item1);
                }
                temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    endOfFile1 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }
                temp = inputFile2.ReadLine();
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    endOfFile2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item2 = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
                {
                    sw.WriteLine(item2);
                }
                temp = inputFile2.ReadLine();
                if (temp == null)
                {
                    endOfFile2 = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    item2 = Int32.Parse(temp);
                }
            }
        }
        while (!endOfFile1)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item1);
            }
            temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
            if (temp == null)
            {
                endOfFile1 = true;

            }
            else
            {
                item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
            }
        }
        while (!endOfFile2)
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
            {
                sw.WriteLine(item2);
            }
            temp = inputFile2.ReadLine();
            if (temp == null)
            {
                endOfFile2 = true;
            }
            else
            {
                item2 = Int32.Parse(temp);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

As the others have pointed out, there is a lot of repetition in your code. 
This is however a great opportunity to threat the files as simple iterators from which you can extract integers. This is done using a simple C# generator.

```
IEnumerator<int> ToIterator(StreamReader reader)
{
   string line;
   while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
   {
      yield return Convert.ToInt32(line);
   }
}
```

Afterwards, simply follow the algorithm you initially described, but substitute `List` with an iterator (`IEnumerator` in .NET terms):

```
void MergeIntegersFiles(string source1, string source2, string destination)
{
   using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(source1))
   {
      using (var reader2 = new StreamReader(source2))
      {
         using (var writer = new StreamWriter(destination))
         {
            var iterator1 = ToIterator(reader1);
            var iterator2 = ToIterator(reader2);
            var iterator1StillAvailable = iterator1.MoveNext();
            var iterator2StillAvailable = iterator2.MoveNext();

            while (iterator1StillAvailable && iterator2StillAvailable)
            {
               if (iterator1.Current <= iterator2.Current)
               {
                  writer.WriteLine(iterator1.Current);
                  iterator1StillAvailable = iterator1.MoveNext();
               }
               else
               {
                  writer.WriteLine(iterator2.Current);
                  iterator2StillAvailable = iterator2.MoveNext();
               }
            }

            //check which iterator can still provide values
            var iteratorRemaining = iterator1StillAvailable
               ? iterator1
               : iterator2StillAvailable ? iterator2 : null;

            if (null != iteratorRemaining)
            {
               do
               {
                   writer.WriteLine(iteratorRemaining.Current);                      
               } while (iteratorRemaining.MoveNext());
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Abstracting further, you create a method which combines arbitrary iterators of sorted values:

```
IEnumerable<T> GetSortedValues<T>(IEnumerator<T> iterator1, IEnumerator<T> iterator2) where T : IComparable<T>
{
   var iterator1StillAvailable = iterator1.MoveNext();
   var iterator2StillAvailable = iterator2.MoveNext();

   while (iterator1StillAvailable && iterator2StillAvailable)
   {
      if (iterator1.Current.CompareTo(iterator2.Current) < 1)
      {
         yield return iterator1.Current;
         iterator1StillAvailable = iterator1.MoveNext();
      }
      else
      {
         yield return iterator2.Current;
         iterator2StillAvailable = iterator2.MoveNext();
      }
   }

   //check which iterator can still provide values
   var iteratorRemaining = iterator1StillAvailable
      ? iterator1
      : iterator2StillAvailable ? iterator2 : null;

   if (null != iteratorRemaining)
   {
      do
      {
         yield return iteratorRemaining.Current;
      } while (iteratorRemaining.MoveNext());
   }
}
```

Which leads you to a simple function that just iterates through something created from two stream readers and writer the result back:

```
void MergeIntegersFiles(string source1, string source2, string destination)
{
   using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(source1))
   {
      using (var reader2 = new StreamReader(source2))
      {
         using (var writer = new StreamWriter(destination))
         {
            foreach (var value in GetSortedValues(ToIterator(reader1), ToIterator(reader2)))
            {
               writer.WriteLine(value);
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: I guess I was a notch late but still your approach is not quite the same as mine. Also you meant `IEnumerable` and not `IEnumerator`

Comment: `yield return` works with both `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerator`. If I had returned an `IEnumerable` I would have requested it's `IEnumerator` anyway, so I decided to simply return the enumerator.

Comment: Nice, A thing that seems for some reason I wasn't aware of.

Comment: I like the iterator approach primarily because it is unit testable; you can pass in any two ordered lists.  The only change I would make would be pass the string (filename) into the ToIterator and open the StreamReader inside the ToIterator.  That way the caller is not responsible for opening and closing the stream.

Comment: You can make the `using`s even prettier by removing the `{}` between them. They are not necessary. `using`s can be written directly one below the other.

Answer (score 5):

First some more general remarks on your code not yet identified:

> ```
> temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
> if (temp == null)
> {
>     endOfFile1 = true;
> }
> ```

The most reasonable way to tell if there is a new line or not usually comes into this code:

```
string line;
while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
```

Saves space, is readable, is concise. When I first started programming I always had those issues when reading line from files, from the moment I saw that I don't want another thing.

`pathInputFile1` We normally suggest to use descriptive names but I admit that `file1` is plenty for me.

---

You are having some trouble because you are doing three different tasks on your algorithm. I can identify at least three steps to achieve a solution for your problem:

- Read the integers from the files
- Merge the integers
- Write the merged integers to a new file

The major problem here is that we may not want to use additional memory, because of that we need to implement all algorithms on a lazily fashion.

```
public static IEnumerable<int> ReadIntegers(string file)
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenText(file))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = stream.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            yield return int.Parse(line);
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<int> UnionSorted(IEnumerable<int> first, IEnumerable<int> second)
{
    var it1 = first.GetEnumerator();
    var it2 = second.GetEnumerator();

    bool it1HasNext = it1.MoveNext();
    bool it2HasNext = it2.MoveNext();
    while (it1HasNext && it2HasNext)
    {
        if (it1.Current > it2.Current)
        {
            yield return it2.Current;
            it2HasNext = it2.MoveNext();
        }
        else
        {
            yield return it1.Current;
            it1HasNext = it1.MoveNext();
        }
    }

    while (it1.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return it1.Current;
    }


    while (it2.MoveNext())
    {
        yield return it2.Current;
    }
}

public static void MergeFiles(string file1, string file2, string ouputFile)
{
    var merged = UnionSorted(ReadIntegers(file1), ReadIntegers(file2));
    using (var writer = File.AppendText(ouputFile))
    {
        foreach (var number in merged)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(number);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Do not open and close the file stream of the output file each time you write one line. Instead open it once at the beginning and close it at the end (open/close a file stream is an expensive operation).

---

Put all the code in a try finally block. Close all file streams in the finally block to ensure that the streams will be closed if an exception occured.

---

Use `TryParse` instad of `Parse` if the format may be invalid.

---

If the output file already exists, the merged content will be appended (not sure if that is desired)

---

There are a lot of code fragements that seems to be duplicates. e.g.:

```
if (temp == null)
{
    endOfFile1 = true;
}
else
{
    item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
}
```

You could extract that in a separate method

```
bool TryGetNextNumber(FileStream strem, out number)
{
    number = -1;
    var line = inputFile1.ReadLine();
    if (line == null) return false;
    return int.TryParse(line, out number);
}
```

---

Maybe there is also a more elegent solution than the 3 while loops... I have to think about it...

Comment: the two StreamReaders should be included in the single using block, rather than try / finally'ing them

Answer (score 1):

This is used multiple times, so it should be moved to a method:

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.AppendText(pathOutputFile))
{
    sw.WriteLine(item1);
}
```

Same for this:

```
temp = inputFile1.ReadLine();
if (temp == null)
{
    endOfFile1 = true;
}
else
{
    item1 = Int32.Parse(temp);
}
```

You should avoid copy-pasting: if you're doing that, chances are you're doing something wrong.

---

Care about names: `temp` is a bad variable name.